# Marketing Cloud Tag Hits 3000!

Tags: discussion

Anyone that works with marketing cloud would know that finding information can be hard.. most of the time support is clueless and online resources are inconsistent. This community has helped me a lot and looking forward to it grow more!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Glad to see the use of this site is expanding! I'm sure [Eliot Harper](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/5449/eliot-harper) has had a lot to do with that as well :)